# Why should I use Apache C++ Standard Library rather than any other STL implementation along with Boost?

Tags: c++, apache, stl

What benefits do I get from [Apache C++ standard library](http://stdcxx.apache.org/) that I don't get from STL implementations that come with the compiler and from Boost libraries?

Comment: I was suggested to use Apache's C++ standard library in my project since it is 'portable' and also has rich set of collections and many other algorithm implementations. I don't want to blindly follow the suggestion, so looking for input from people that have better knowledge and experience using different template libraries. Thanks.

Comment: About your Boost part: are you asking if you should use Apache C++ Standard Library in place of Boost? Or Boost in place of an STL implementation

Comment: I have been using STL and Boost where needed (eg. smart pointers). So the question is stdxx in place of stl and boost. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Apache C++ Standard Library
>   project is a complete implementation
>   of the ISO/IEC 14882 C++ Standard
>   Library.
>
> The most distinguishing characteristic
>   of this implementation of the C++
>   Standard Library is its portability to
>   a large number of C++ compilers,
>   operating systems, and hardware
>   architectures.

Sounds like if you value extreme portability this is for you.  If you don't, most everyone defaults to their compiler's default implementation, so if you ever have trouble, the community will be bigger.  If you don't run into implementation issues I don't see why it should make much of a difference.

I typically get flamed for this opinion but I like the idea of having a company I can pay to fix problems, my developers (and I) aren't smart enough (or don't have the time) to dive into internals and fix bugs.

Answer (score 5):

One of the advantages that `stdxx` claims seems to be true to me:

> - Optimized for fast compiles and
>     extremely small executable file sizes

In this paper, Stroustrup talks about a new idea applied in some C++ compilers called [`SCARY`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2913.pdf). I first read about it in [one of his papers](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/SCARY.pdf). Anyway, this *feature* allows reducing produced executables size by a great amount `(~1x - ~25x)`, and faster by `(~1.2x - ~2.1x)`. In the first paper, he said that `Rogue Wave STL` supports `SCARY`, at least in modern implementations:

> The most recent version of Rogue Wave
>   STL has independent container
>   iterators in its production mode, but
>   some of the standard containers’
>   iterators are not independent in debug
>   mode. N2911 explains that these
>   dependencies are not actually required
>   for debugging purposes and can easily
>   be removed.

So, if `stdxx` is based on `Rogue Wave STL`, it might have this idea implemented already.

Comment: stdxx was forked in 2005; the SCARY paper is much more recent.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this library is no longer supported as of July 2013. See the mailing list announcement:  http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/stdcxx-dev/201307.mbox/browser

Answer (score 0):

Apache C++ library was originally a commercial library from Rogue Wave. They claim to be tracking the C++ standard very closely and working hard to insure portability across various operating systems and compilers. The Rogue Wave library claimed to have been ported to over 40 compilers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Apache C++ Standard Library, so I'm not sure what facilities it has. If you find that it provides everything that you need, then there is not much of a difference using that or using another STL implementation alongside Boost. However, Boost provides a lot more than some TR1 features and little things like smart pointers. It also has:

1. Lambdas/Closures
2. Template and preprocessor metaprogramming
3. Signals and slots/Observer/Listener pattern implementation
4. Reference wrappers
5. A lot of other random things you're not likely to find elsewhere in a single library

It all depends on the facilities that you need.